# Unable to get current latitude and longitude of current location in Android

Tags: android, android-location

I use below code to get current location of user. This code work  in emulator but when I use this application in mobile it unable to give current latitude and longitude. 
I uses `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />` this code in android manifest file.

Please give me solution... my code is below

```
public class MenuPage extends Activity{



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menupage);


     LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
     LocationListener locListener = new MyLocationListener();
     locationManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locListener);



}
```

/* Start of Class MyLocationListener for get current location of user  */

```
public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener

{

    @Override

    public void onLocationChanged(Location crurrentLocation)

    {
          Log.v("WHERE ","onLocationChanged()");
          crurrentLocation.getLatitude(); // get current latitude
          crurrentLocation.getLongitude(); // get current longitude
           longitude=crurrentLocation.getLongitude();
           latitude=  crurrentLocation.getLatitude();

           Log.v("WHERE ","onLocationChanged()  Latitude="+latitude);   
           Log.v("WHERE ","onLocationChanged()  Longitude="+longitude); 
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Latitud="+crurrentLocation.getLatitude(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Longitud="+crurrentLocation.getLongitude(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            send_current_location = new Send_Current_location_ToServer();
      // Send current location to server
            String server_message =  send_current_location.sendData(userid,latitude,longitude);    
         //   String text ="My current location is: " + "Latitud = " + crurrentLocation.getLatitude() + "Longitud = " + crurrentLocation.getLongitude();
         //   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),text,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)

    {
          Log.v("WHERE ","onProviderDisabled()");
    Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),"Gps Disabled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

    }

    @Override

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)

    {
         Log.v("WHERE ","onProviderEnabled()");

    Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),"Gps Enabled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)

    {
         Log.v("WHERE ","onStatusChanged()");
    }

}/* End of Class MyLocationListener */
```

}

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in the 2.3 emulator concerning the location services. Try changing to 2.1 to test your code.

For more info about location services, use [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html).

See [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13015) for the status of the bug.